# SQL Server: Deleted and inserted table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use below code to see the inserted row

```
INSERT INTO Costumer VALUES (N'Mah',N'Ahm','1988/5/5')
SELECT * FROM INSERTED
```

But I see this error on SQL Server 2008 R2

> (1 row(s) affected)
>       Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>       Invalid object name 'INSERTED'.

What's wrong?

Comment: try `select * from Costumer`... `INSERTED ` is reserved Keyword use in Triggers

Comment: Take a look [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Comment: I strongly suggest an explicit column list instead of the shortcut `*` for all columns in production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like:

```
insert into Costumer 
output inserted.* 
values(N'Mah',N'Ahm','1988/5/5')
```